# Elastic Search: SearchAsync call from NEST Throwing Exception regarding ThreadPool

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Elasticsearch.Net.UnexpectedElasticsearchClientException: There were not enough free threads in the ThreadPool to complete the operation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There were not enough free threads in the ThreadPool to complete the operation

If i use the Search method of the IElasticClient iterface the operation performs the search successfully.

Also .. i have a hard time believing it's a setting on the elastic server since the call works fine on another machine.

Any ideas what thread pool this is referring to? Much appreciated.

Comment: This is an issue on your application's side. Can you write us the configuration you use in nest to connect on Elastic? How you open the client?

Comment: you're right, it's not on ES side. that's the  app. i guess you are missing something while using async approach. how are you calling it? maybe in a loop or?

Comment: Well i'm able to use the SearchAsync without a problem when on my vpn using my local windows 10 machine... but this problem happens when running the same application on a Windows Server... Maybe i need to be looking at help from Windows Server Configurations?

Answer (score 0):

Discovered there was a piece of code in the application that was setting the threadpool

```
ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(maxWorkerCount, maxIOCount);
```

because the virtual server was set to have only 2 processors.. so this code set the max threads to 2.  This caused the async calls of the application on that machine to throw those errors.